# How can I toggle the margin of an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I am trying to move a div to the side, and back, with a transition, by changing the margin. I have one button that I want to toggle it's margin. The div moves to the right,but when I click again, it doesn't move back to it's original position. This is what I have:

HTML

```
<div id="movingdiv">
<a href="#" onclick="toggle()">Click Me!</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#movingdiv {
overflow: hidden;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: gray;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function toggle () {

var el = document.getElementById("movingdiv");
if ( el.style.marginLeft="250px" ) {

    el.style.marginLeft="250px";

}

else {

    el.style.marginLeft="0px";

}

}
```

Here it is in action:
http://codepen.io/dakoder/pen/nfimJ

Comment: Please don't ask users to reverse-engineer external sites. Please post the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're making an assignment, instead of checking equality. In addition, you have your `else` condition and `if` condition mixed. Change it to the following:

```
if ( el.style.marginLeft==="250px" ) {
    el.style.marginLeft="0px";
} else {
    el.style.marginLeft="250px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
if ( el.style.marginLeft==="250px" ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( el.style.marginLeft="250px" ) {
```

This is assigning, not comparing. Use ===, or !== if you want to toggle the margin (as appears to be your intention).